# Why is my Maven not using the defined BOM?

Tags: java, maven

I am currently trying to introduce a BOM (bill of materials) file to my Maven project, but it does not seem to work and I have no clue, why.

This is my **bom**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.private</groupId>
  <artifactId>test.bom</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <version.CoreAnnotation>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version.CoreAnnotation>
    <version.CoreWeb>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version.CoreWeb>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.private</groupId>
        <artifactId>CoreAnnotation</artifactId>
        <version> ${version.CoreAnnotation}</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.private</groupId>
        <artifactId>CoreWeb</artifactId>
        <version>${version.CoreWeb}</version>
        <type>war</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

There are **many more**, but I excluded them because I think this should be enough as an example.

This is my **pom** (where I try to include the bom):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>Core</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.private</groupId>
    <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>Core-ear</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <name>Core-ear: EAR Module for private</name>

  <properties>
    <version.test.bom>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version.test.bom>
  </properties>


  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.private</groupId>
        <artifactId>test.bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.test.bom}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Whenever I use **maven install** there should be a collection of all packages defined in the dependencies section appear in the folder \target\Core-ear\

Now the problem: The dependencies defined in the bom don't appear there. What could be the problem?

ps: running `mvn install -X` for debugging does not seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you did not declare the dependencies in your POM. You only declared the `<dependencyManagement>` section.

In your POM, you need to add the following dependencies, without the version:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.private</groupId>
    <artifactId>CoreAnnotation</artifactId>
    <type>ejb</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.private</groupId>
    <artifactId>CoreWeb</artifactId>
    <type>war</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.private</groupId>
      <artifactId>test.bom</artifactId>
      <version>${version.test.bom}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Refer to [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies): BOM are used to factor version of all the artifacts, so you don't need to add it in your `<dependency>` section.

Comment: `dependencyManagement` is for the top level pom, to have all possible dependencies declared with their version. In the child poms then inside all `dependencies` the `<version>...` can then be left out.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes and I did not specify them and explicitely said "without the version", twice. I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: Sorry, that was just additional info on what dependencyManagement is for. As there seemed to have been the cause for the error. Voted +1

Comment: It tells me, that the version is missing for the given dependency

Comment: @DoRe See my edit, I think you added the dependencies at the wrong place. It should not be under `<dependenciesManagement>`.

Comment: still giving me this error:

`'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.private:CoreAnnotation:ejb is missing. @ com.private:Core-ear:[unknown-version], C:\PM-Scada\Java\Workspace\Core-ear\pom.xml, line 25, column 17`

Comment: @DoRe Did you install your BOM project running `mvn clean install`? Then run `mvn clean install` on your project.

Comment: Installing the BOM was no problem. mvn clean install on the pom first told me, that there was a folder missing in \target\ directory. after creating the folder named as the required one, I had a successful build, but the dependencies still missing

Comment: @DoRe Something must be wrong on your setup. You should not need to create a folder by hand, especially inside `target`, since `clean` will delete it anyway. Are you running Maven from the command line or from an IDE?

Comment: Currently eclipse, but I tried from the cmdline, too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96247/discussion-between-tunaki-and-do-re).